# Automating custom VMware VMs for development

Tags: vmware-workstation

One of my tasks is to provide up-to-date VMs for different releases of our software. We have a three tier strategy: the top level (golden) contains purely development and utility software, and a working copy of the Common portion of our Subversion repository; the next level (silver) contains the latest binaries for a specific release, and the latest source code pertaining for the product; the final level (bronze) is essentially a copy of silver that is to be used by a specific developer (so it will require, at the least, a new host name and auto-logon user name/password pair).

I would like to automate the gold => silver and then silver => bronze transitions as much as possible. Ideally, I would like it if I never had to go into VMware Workstation at all, and just run a script. All the VMs are located on the network, but for efficiency, I keep a copy of them on my hard disk as a staging-area. The gold => silver script would run on my machine.  But it would be nice if the end-users ran a script to copy the VM off the network, and then did the final customisation in one go.

If people could give me general advice, and point out which bits are just impossible, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my series on VMWare with automation and some other stuff (servers / clusters / etc).  I hope it helps....

http://tsells.wordpress.com/category/virtualization/vmware-virtualization/